# Is gamma wave the same thing as gamma rays?

Tags: waves

Gamma rays are dangerous,however we have brain gamma waves:

- Are gamma waves the same thing as gamma rays?
- What is the difference between this two waves?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks elementary research.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero,can't find any research about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're totally unrelated. "Gamma" is the third letter of the Greek alphabet; naming things "alpha, beta, gamma, delta" is not very different from naming them "A, B, C, D" (like we did historically for vitamins).

When radiation was first observed from heavy-metal ores, it became clear that it came in positively-charged, negatively-charged, and electrically neutral flavors. With no other information, those species were labeled as alpha, beta, and gamma rays. Now we know that gamma rays are lumps of electromagnetic radiation, like light, with much more energy per lump than visible light, but the old name has stuck.

I learned with my son at the science museum last week that four of the recognized types of neural activity patterns are alpha, beta, gamma, and theta (another Greek letter name)  which I think is like how there's a vitamin K but not a vitamin G. A biology community would be a better place to learn about how the different types of neuro-electric patterns are actually different from each other.

Answer (score 2):

In the brain, a "gamma wave" is a slowly spreading wave of electrical activity in the brain's neurons, which can be detected with an electroencephalogram device.

A gamma ray is something completely different: it is an extremely energetic photon that is fired off during reactions that take place in an atom's nucleus.

Their names are coincidentally similar; physically they have nothing to do with each other.